# Confused about class method syntax

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, math, addition

How do I pass `first_number` and `second_number` to the `+add_function`? 
I am currently getting math undeclared.

Additionally, I have placed the pound include `math_class` in the `-addButtonClicked:` `IBAction`.

Also, I realize that I can simply add the two numbers in the IBAction, but for learning purposes I would like to pass them to my `math_class`.

```
-(IBAction)addButtonClicked    
{
    double total;
    double first_number = [firstNumberField.text doubleValue];
    double second_number = [secondNumberField.text doubleValue];

    total = [math_class.add_function number_one:first_number number_two:second_number]; 
    answerField.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", total];

    [answerField setHidden:NO];
}

@interface math_class : NSObject

+ (double) add_function: (double) number_one: (double) number_two;

@end

@implementation math_class

+(double) add_function: (double) number_one: (double) number_two
{
    double total;
    total = number_one + number_two;
    return total;
}

@end
```

Comment: Is `add_function` a property on `math_class`? That line of code is hard to understand

Comment: We need more code. What is the method signature for `add_function`?. Also, what is `math_class`?

Comment: Your syntax is rather confused. Have a look at [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the code you posted.

First of all, the convention in Cocoa Touch is that class names use camel-case and start with a capital letter: `MathClass`, *not* `math_class`.  Method names use camel-case and each keyword starts with a lower-case letter.  If you stick to the naming convention, it will be easier for other people to understand your code, so it will be easier for you to get help when you have a problem.

Now, in your `math_class` class, you have declared a method like this:

```
+ (double) add_function: (double) number_one: (double) number_two;
```

But you've put in spaces and left out spaces in an unusual way.  The usual way to write it, keeping exactly the same method name, looks like this:

```
+ (double)add_function:(double)number_one :(double)number_two;
```

The name of this method is `add_function::`, **not** `add_function number_one:number_two:` (which is what you used to try to call it).

This method name has two keywords.  The first keyword is `add_function:` and takes a `double` argument named `number_one`.  The second keyword is just `:` and takes a `double` argument named `number_two`.

You *could* call this method like this:

```
total = [math_class add_function:first_number :second_number];
```

However, using a method name with a keyword of just `:` is almost always very bad style.

There are lots of ways to write your class in good style.  Here's one way:

```
@interface MathClass : NSObject

+ (double)sumWithNumber:(double)firstNumber number:(double)secondNumber;

@end

@implementation MathClass

+ (double)sumWithNumber:(double)firstNumber number:(double)secondNumber {
    return firstNumber + secondNumber;
}

@end
```

When a method is used primarily for its return value, and not for side effects, we name it after the thing it returns.  So I called it `sumWithNumber:number:` because it returns a sum.

The method name has two keywords.  The first keyword is `sumWithNumber:` and takes a `double` argument named `firstNumber`.  The second keyword is `number:` and takes a `double` argument named `secondNumber`.  You can call it like this:

```
total = [MathClass sumWithNumber:first_number number:second_number];
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to access a function using the objective-c dot property syntax.  If add_function is defined as:

```
+(void) add_function: ...
```

.. and math_class is the class name you should use

```
[match_class add_function number_one:.......
```

Note space rather than dot.

edit now you've posted the code:

Your definition for the add_function is wrong - in obj-c you need to give the name of the parameter AND the name of the variable unlike in most other languages.

Here's what add_function signature could look like:

```
+(double) add_function_number_one: (double) number_one  number_two: (double) number_two
```

There's a convention in cocoa that the name of the function includes the name of the first parameter, hence why it's now called add_function_number_one.

Comment: Updated currently getting Expected ']' before 'first_number'

Answer (score -1):

You should probably be calling `[math_class add_function:first_number:second_number];` Your class is called math_class, not math.

Comment: Fixed and replaced with suggestion you provided and currently receiving error: Expected ']' before 'first_number'

Comment: it's a bit rude to be -1'ing people trying to help you, when they posted before you updated your question.

Comment: Ben I certainly appreciate your help and didn't "-1" you. I've answered YES to the question about was this helpful to you. Don't know how you or anyone else ended up with -1. Again...thank you for your help. Additionally, I just noted that to vote down you need 125 reputation points. I only have 1, thus I can't vote down or up for that matter.